# How to make a dropdown menu show up in the top navbar using Creative Tim's Material Dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Creative Tim's material dashboard that is based off bootstrap. The demo page shows a set notification and user dropdown menu items. I am trying to create the first set for the notification. Here is the source code, then I will explain further.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:;">Your Monthly Reports</a>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdownNotifications" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class='material-icons'>notifications</i>
                        <span class='notification'>1</span>
                        <p class='d-lg-none d-md-block'>Notifications</p>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownNotifications">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item">Some Action</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I cannot seem to get the dropdown menu to actually SHOW. Oh the element changes classes and gets the show, showing, hide, & hiding elements when appropriate, and upon inspecting the element and focusing on it, it shows that the element is "locating" itself in the right place, but you just cannot see it. I have even tried altering the z-index, and other styling of `div.dropdown-menu` using the element inspector, but it doesn't seem to want to show its face.

I even looked on the 3D view to see if something was in front of it, and there isn't. The display for the element is not none and has all the elements you would expect to see. But the issue is that you can't see it when you click the notification icon. It changes the DOM code, but nothing changes visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was something not related to anything I had shared. I also had altered the theme using colormind.io. The issue was that the drop down menu was being incorrectly altered. I found the rule that had changed its VISIBILITY to hidden, but the on click function had actually not be updated correctly.